# Moving Emails from Previous Weekday Doing Nothing

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to put together Outlook VBA to find all emails in the primary inbox from the previous weekday (Monday-Friday) and move them to a new folder, which I am also creating.

I tried to add in the logic to skip Saturday and Sunday. Since today is Monday, I should be moving all emails from Friday. It successfully creates the new folder with last Friday's date, but it doesn't move any emails. Last I checked, on Friday it did move the Thursday items. I'm struggling to determine why it wont move last Friday's emails today?

My question is, can anyone determine why Friday's emails are not being moved at all?

Below is the code I currently use:

```
Sub Move_Yesterdays_Emails()

'***Creates a new folder named yesterdays date under the inbox***

 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim xDay As String
 Dim XDate As Date

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        XDate = Date - 3
    Else
        XDate = Date - 1
    End If

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add(XDate)

'***Releases memory***

 Set myNameSpace = Nothing
 Set myFolder = Nothing
 Set myNewFolder = Nothing

'***Finds all emails in the inbox from yesterday and moves them to the created folder***

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim i As Long

        Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
              CStr(XDate) & _
             " 12:00AM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & _
              CStr(XDate) & " 12:00AM'"

        Debug.Print Filter

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Debug.Print Items(i)
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Item.Move Inbox.Folders(XDate)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance. I'd like to get this solved today, so I don't have to wait until next Monday to try the situation live again.

Comment: do you see the `Debug.Print Items(i)`?

Comment: @ThomasG  No I do not see them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues with your code, I fixed everything and it now runs fine

The main mistake: your filter was

```
 [ReceivedTime] >= '15/06/2018 12:00AM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '15/06/2018 12:00AM'
```

So basically it searched for nothing as the 2 datetime in between were the same. You should make your filter like this

```
    Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
          CStr(XDate) & _
         " 12:00AM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & _
          CStr(XDate + 1) & " 12:00AM'"
```

You also had issue with the `Item.Move`. You should specify an Outlook.Folder type of object there

Whole sub becomes

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Yesterdays_Emails()


'***Creates a new folder named yesterdays date under the inbox***

 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim xDay As String
 Dim XDate As Date

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        XDate = Date - 3
    Else
        XDate = Date - 1
    End If

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add(XDate)

'***Finds all emails in the inbox from yesterday and moves them to the created folder***

    'Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace ---> DUPLICATE DECLARATION
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim i As Long

        Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
              CStr(XDate) & _
             " 12:00AM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & _
              CStr(XDate + 1) & " 12:00AM'"

        Debug.Print Filter

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Debug.Print Items(i)
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Item.Move myNewFolder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: wow, thanks for fixing it! so my main issue was that I was missing the `XDate + 1` to set the second date as the next day (saturday)...seems painfully obvious once you pointed it out. works like a charm now.